# При уменьшение масштаба экрана, фоновое изображение слишком сжимается, не занимая всю ширину экрана

Tags: html, css

```
[![Вот так выглядит экран][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlPgU.png
## CSS ##
.forum__background{
  background-image: url("/img/header/bgc.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  top:90px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте установить ширину на 100vw, чтобы блок занял всю ширину области просмотра.

Если не выйдет, нужно посмотреть ширину родителя .forum__background

Comment: `нужно посмотреть ширину` — предположим, что автор вопроса посмотрел эту самую ширину. и что ему дальше делать с этой информацией? пожалуйста, напишите об этом прямо в тексте ответа, нажав [edit].

Comment: я остановился на варианте, с фиксированной шириной. На ширине когда процентная ширина перестала занимать всю ширину экрана,  я сменил 100% на фиксированную ширину... Вариант с 100vw не помог, в родительских классах нету ограничений по ширине